# Wow! More Riddles

Tags: riddle

> A very majestic thing I am
>
> That many people can use
>
> But not all can master me
>
> As it takes a lot of effort to do so
>
> I am divided into 2 : Black and White
>
> And each Black or White you press
>
> Will produce something majestic
>
> I am almost like a bicycle
>
> Except that I have 3 and not 2 pedals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> a piano?

I am divided into 2 : Black and White

> keys

Except that I have 3 and not 2 pedals

> a piano usually has 3 pedals

Comment: Correct! Which part gave it away? @Eutherpy

Comment: @KevinL The pedals, but I'm a musician so it might just be my disposition :D

Comment: Lol! I knew that the pedals was a really big hint but still wrote that. Still that was fast :))

Comment: @KevinL rot13(sbe zr vg jnf gur "cerffvat" bs gur oynpx naq juvgr)

Comment: oh I thought that hint wasn't too obvious @Cashbee